# Spring MVC xml based configuration - blank page

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm trying to write my first Spring MVC application and I got stuck with an issue I can't resolve.

When I run application on Tomcat  it starts but whenever I request the url handled by the controller it goes into the controller but does not return a view.

I know that there are many similar questions on the web. None of which helped me resolve my problem unfortunately.

So I write in IntellijIdea 2016.2.3 and have Maven support for the project.
My Tomcat server is 8.5 version.

So I have a controller file that looks as follows:

MyController.java

```
package com.example.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

/**
 * Created by tomko_2 on 2017-03-07.
 */
@Controller
public class MyController {

        @RequestMapping("/mytest")
        public String home() {

            System.out.println("controller at work");
            return "index";
        }
}
```

Application.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

/**
 * Created by tomko_2 on 2017-03-08.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public Application() {
        super();
        setRegisterErrorPageFilter(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Here is my server output log. The second line looks suspicious, but I wasn't able to find why it looks so.

```
"C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\catalina.bat" run
[2017-03-12 10:22:49,247] Artifact spring-mvc-show:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\tomko_2\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_spring-mvc-show"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jan 10 2017 21:02:52 UTC
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.11.0
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 8.1
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.3
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_73-b02
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\tomko_2\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_spring-mvc-show
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\tomko_2\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_spring-mvc-show\conf\logging.properties
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\tomko_2\.IntelliJIdea2016.2\system\tomcat\Unnamed_spring-mvc-show
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.10 using APR version 1.5.2.
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
12-Mar-2017 22:22:50.475 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.507 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016)
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.725 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.757 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.772 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.772 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1872 ms
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.835 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.835 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.851 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.866 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
12-Mar-2017 22:22:51.866 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 92 ms
Connected to server
[2017-03-12 10:22:51,991] Artifact spring-mvc-show:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
12-Mar-2017 22:22:54.991 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

2017-03-12 22:22:56.851  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] com.example.Application                  : Starting Application on komp-TN with PID 208 (started by tomko_2 in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin)
2017-03-12 22:22:56.866  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] com.example.Application                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-03-12 22:22:56.960  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7de0fc9: startup date [Sun Mar 12 22:22:56 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-12 22:22:58.991  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-12 22:22:59.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'validator' of type [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-12 22:22:59.195  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2235 ms
2017-03-12 22:23:00.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-12 22:23:00.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-12 22:23:00.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-12 22:23:00.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-12 22:23:00.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-12 22:23:00.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-12 22:23:00.976  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7de0fc9: startup date [Sun Mar 12 22:22:56 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-12 22:23:01.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/mytest]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.controller.MyController.home()
2017-03-12 22:23:01.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-03-12 22:23:01.148  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-03-12 22:23:01.242  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-12 22:23:01.242  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-12 22:23:01.335  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-12 22:23:01.742  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-03-12 22:23:01.789  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] com.example.Application                  : Started Application in 6.251 seconds (JVM running for 12.433)
2017-03-12 22:23:01.835  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
2017-03-12 22:23:01.835  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext       : Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Sun Mar 12 22:23:01 CET 2017]; parent: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7de0fc9
2017-03-12 22:23:01.835  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.f.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader      : Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
12-Mar-2017 22:23:01.851 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager
12-Mar-2017 22:23:02.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager has finished in 375 ms
2017-03-12 22:23:04.070  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-03-12 22:23:04.117  INFO 208 --- [on(5)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 2282 ms
[2017-03-12 10:23:04,132] Artifact spring-mvc-show:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2017-03-12 10:23:04,132] Artifact spring-mvc-show:war exploded: Deploy took 12 141 milliseconds
controller at work
2017-03-12 22:27:25.668 ERROR 208 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/mytest] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

As you can see controller is running ("controller at work" in second last line), but no view is returned.

My project structure is as follows:

```
src  
----main  
--------java  
------------com.example  
----------------config  
----------------controller  
--------------------MyController.java  
----------------Application.java  
----test  
--------java  
web  
----WEB-INF  
--------pages  
------------index.jsp  
--------applicationContext.xml  
--------dispatcher-servlet.xml  
--------web.xml
----META-INF
--------context.xml
pom.xml
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I have no applicationContext.xml file since I have only one servlet and application is really simple. I just want it to get work.

index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  $END$
  </body>
</html>
```

/META-INF/context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/">
</Context>
```

edit:
I put there also my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mvc-show</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Unfortunately my reputation doesn't allow me to include some pictures from IntelliJ, so I'm going to describe it precisely:

file->project structure->facets->web:

I have 2 deployment descriptors there:

```
Web Module Deployment Descriptor (path_to_project/web/WEB-INF/web.xml)

Tomcat Context Descriptor (path_to_project/web/META-INF/context.xml)

Web Resource Directory (path_to_project/web)
```

file->project structure->facets->spring:

```
Spring Application Context (dispatcher-servlet.xml) # here I'm not sure if it should be so, maybe I need applicationContext.xml, but as my project is really simple and based on single servlet I wanted to place all configuration in dispatcher-servlet.xml
MVC dispatcher servlet context (dispatcher-servlet.xml)
Application (Application)
```

run->edit configurations:

I have my local Tomcat server registered there.
In deployment tab I have only war:exploded with applicationContext "/"

Forgive me if I made really silly mistake, but I'm coping with Spring MVC basic configuration for half a week and I'm totally out of ideas what could be wrong there.

Comment: Remove the application.java and deploy and check

Comment: Thank you. It was a really good point, but in fact not the last issue. The problem was also with invalid schema location for spring mvc which was somehow replaced with spring cache in the 5th and 6th line of dispatcher-servlet,xml. Now it works, though it still displays: "Artifact spring-mvc-show:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available." at application run.

Comment: Remove cache xsd location from dispatchservlet file.i don't see anywhere u used this.

Comment: Now it looks it should look like. Thank you very much.